# How to convert all .xlsm of particular folder to .xlsx using Bash scripting on windows

Tags: bash, window

I want to convert all .xlsm of a particular folder to .xlsx and for this I want to write a bash script and scheduled it on window.

Answer (score 2):

first install the libreoffice:

```
sudo apt install libreoffice unoconv
```

then use the unoconv tool that comes with libreoffice to do the conversion:

```
cd /folder/containing/.xlsmfiles
unoconv -f xlsx *
```

the -f tells of the expected output format and the * is the input files

make sure that all the files in the folder are xlms files else unoconv would throw an error

UPDATE: a basic script to work on only the xlsm files in the mixture of other file formats

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in /path/to/folder/*.xlsm; do unoconv -f xlsx "$f"; done
```

replace  with the absolute path to the folder containing the files. save the file. remember to make the script executable.

Comment: Thanks for replying but folder contain many files with different format . So, I want to make script that search .xlsm and convert them.